# Mirror Checkmates

Tags: chess

A mirrored game is a game where black makes the same moves as white. Doing this, find the fastest possible checkmates for:

- A Regular Rook
- A Promoted Rook
- A Regular Bishop
- A Promoted Bishop
- A Regular Knight
- A Promoted Knight
- A Promoted Queen
- A Pawn

May you have fun finding out the answers!

Comment: This seems way too chess and less puzzle to me.

Comment: What do you mean copy0cat questions? Also, just because it'll get shelled in CSE doesn't mean it belongs here either.

Comment: @North What does that even mean? Being chessy doesn't make something not a puzzle ...

Comment: Does every move have to be mirrored prior checkmate? Also, is the mirroring a literal reflection. Does the rook on h1 correspond to that on h8 (or a8)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was this question on a competitive programming contest. It asked how to checkmate by **any pieces** (including King!) but not all for promoted one. You may see the full solution here:

> [Problem L - IPSC 2018](https://ipsc.ksp.sk/2018/real/solutions/booklet.pdf)

And here they are:

**Queen**

> 1. d4 d5 2. Qd3 Qd6 3. Qh3 Qh6 4. Qxc8#
>  [Link (online viewer)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=d4_d5_Qd3_Qd6_Qh3_Qh6_Qxc8M)

**Knight**

> 1. Nc3 Nc6 2. Ne4 Ne5 3. e3 e6 4. Ne2 Ne7 5. c3 c6 6. Nd6#
>  [Link (online viewer)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=Nc3_Nc6_Ne4_Ne5_e3_e6_Ne2_Ne7_c3_c6_Nd6M)

**Rook**

> 1. Nf3 Nf6 2. Ng5 Ng4 3. Nxh7 Nxh2 4. Nxf8 Nxf1 5. Ne6 Ne3 6. Rxh8#
>  [Link (online viewer)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=Nf3_Nf6_Ng5_Ng4_Nxh7_Nxh2_Nxf8_Nxf1_Ne6_Ne3_Rxh8M)

**Promoted Rook (and Promoted Queen)**

> 1. c4 c5 2. d4 d5 3. dxc5 dxc4 4. c6 c3 5. c7 c2 6. cxd8=R#
>  [Link (online viewer)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=c4_c5_d4_d5_dxc5_dxc4_c6_c3_c7_c2_cxd8ZRM)

**Pawn**

> 1. f4 f5 2. g4 g5 3. gxf5 gxf4 4. Nf3 Nf6 5. Ng5 Ng4 6. f6 f3 7. f7#
>  [Link (online viewer)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=f4_f5_g4_g5_gxf5_gxf4_Nf3_Nf6_Ng5_Ng4_f6_f3_f7M)

**Bishop**

> 1. e4 e5 2. f4 f5 3. exf5 exf4 4. f6 f3 5. fxg7 fxg2 6. Be2 Be7 7. Bh5#
>  [Link (online viewer)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=e4_e5_f4_f5_exf5_exf4_f6_f3_fxg7_fxg2_Be2_Be7_Bh5M)

**King**

> 1. f3 f6 2. Kf2 Kf7 3. Kg3 Kg6 4. Kh3 Kh6 5. e3 e6 6. Bd3 Bd6 7. Bg6 Bg3 8. hxg3 hxg6 9. Kg4#
>  [Link (online viewer)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=f3_f6_Kf2_Kf7_Kg3_Kg6_Kh3_Kh6_e3_e6_Bd3_Bd6_Bg6_Bg3_hxg3_hxg6_Kg4M)

**Promoted Bishop (*my own answer -- may not be optimal*)**

> 1. g4 g5 2. h4 h5 3. hxg5 hxg4 4. g6 g3 5. g7 g2 6. Nh3 Nh6 7. Ng5 Ng4 8. g8=B g1=B 9. Bxf7#
>  [Link (online viewer)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=g4_g5_h4_h5_hxg5_hxg4_g6_g3_g7_g2_Nh3_Nh6_Ng5_Ng4_g8ZB_g1ZB_Bxf7M)

**Promoted Knight (*my own answer -- may not be optimal*)**

> 1. c4 c5 2. b4 b5 3. cxb5 cxb4 4. b6 b3 5. b7 b2 6. bxc8=N bxc1=N 7. e3 e6 8. Ne2 Ne7 9. Nd6#
>  [Link (online viewer)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=c4_c5_b4_b5_cxb5_cxb4_b6_b3_b7_b2_bxc8ZN_bxc1ZN_e3_e6_Ne2_Ne7_Nd6M)

Comment: @RewanDemontay I've just updated for promoted rook/queen, but not yet for the others ><

Comment: @RewanDemontay added the rests, you may check them ^^

Comment: Nice one! And eh.. is promoted king a thing in chess.. lol

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer**

A Regular Rook

> 1. h4, h5 
>  2. g3, g6 
>  3. Bh3, Bh6 
>  4. Bg4, Bg5 
>  5. hxg5, hxg4 
>  6. Nf3, Nf6 
>  7. Nd4, Nd5 
>  8. Rxh8# 
>  Optimal, clarified by OP.

A Promoted Rook/Promoted Queen

> 1. h4, h5 
>  2. g4, g5 
>  3. hxg5, hxg4 
>  4. g6, g3 
>  5. Bh3, Bh6 
>  6. Be6, Be3 
>  7. Nf3, Nf6 
>  8. Nd4, Nd5 
>  9. g7, g2 
>  10. gxh8R# for the Rook case.
>  or 
>  10. gxh8Q# for the Queen case
>  Not optimal.

A Regular Bishop

> 1. g3, g6 
>  2. Nf3, Nf6 
>  3. Ng5, Ng4 
>  4. Nc3, Nc6 
>  5. Nd5, Nd4 
>  6. Nf4, Nf5 
>  7. Nxg6, Nxg3 
>  8. Bg2, Bg7 
>  9. Bd5, Bd4 
>  10. Bxf7# 
>  Not optimal.

A Regular Knight

> 1. e3, e6 
>  2. Ne2, Ne7 
>  3. g3, g6 
>  4. Nbc3, Nbc6 
>  5. Ne4, Ne5 
>  6. Nf6# 
>  Optimal, clarified by OP.

Comment: I've got a different finishing position. Both knights move. The g-knight only moves in 2 while all other moves are performed with the b-knights. Therefore, you should have knights in front of the kings.

Comment: Here: https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?w=8&h=8&p=PRNBQKBNRPPPPPPPP________________________________pppppppprnbqkbnr0&m=e3_e6_Ne2_Ne7_g3_g6_Nbc3_Nbc6_Ne4_Ne5_Nf6

Comment: Move 4 should be Nbc3, not Nec3, I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: The regular rook is not optimal, can check my answer for this.

Comment: @athin Ah okay, just the knight one then, it seems.